# Backslash at the end of searchword breaks custom search form

Tags: php, wordpress

Accidentally, I discovered that whenever there is a backslash at the end of a search, the page after clicking submit will return a broken search form.

In my case, the submit button turned into a text area.

Using Google Chrome's "inspect element" I saw that my search form turned into this:

```
<form method="get" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="books">
        <input type="text" name="search" value="\">        <input type="&gt;
    &lt;/form&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div id=" sidebar"="" class="sidebar widget-area"></form>
```

The following code is my form. I am guessing that I need to sanitize/escape the value from the input type text? But why isn't `esc_attr()` working?

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($_GET['search'])); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
<input type="checkbox" name="title">
</form>
```

P.S. I am using this custom search form to search custom fields and display the resulting custom post types using Pods Plugin. It doesn't appear that this is a Pods plugin issue though.

https://github.com/pods-framework/pods/issues/1620

Also, this doesn't appear to be a conflict from another theme or plugin.

Comment: You need to escape your data when it gets sent to your processing script.  Show us the script the gets called (on the server side) when you click 'Search.'

Comment: I am using the search form together with pods plugin. The data is processed by it and they insist that it is escaped. They say that this could be a wordpress bug. See link at the bottom of my op post.

Comment: Only way to know for sure is to open the script and see for yourself.

Comment: I tried the form on a test page. Basically the form is intentionally made to do nothing. searched for a backslash and the search form is broken like I said at op post. Done with default wordpress twenty thirteen theme with no plugins enabled.

Comment: Maybe the easiest thing for you would be a javascript solution.  You can try stripping out the slashes before the form is submitted.

Comment: I am wondering if this is an isolated case or are there any other wordpress users experiencing the same? Because I don't remember encountering this issue before the wordpress update.

Comment: It's a good question, Angelica.  I don't know (not a wordpress user).

Comment: may be `rtrim($search,'/');` will work

Comment: Sorry, rtrim didn't work with the backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried dozens of sanitation and escaping. But in the end, only preg_replace worked against that annoying backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some test, I'm guessing that your question was missunderstood, this code should work:

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo urldecode($_GET['search']); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
<input type="checkbox" name="title">
</form>
```

You can check the php [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function for extra info.

Decoding an url is the oposite of encoding it, when a special character is submited it needs to be encoded, when you want to display it you'll have to decode it.

EDIT:
After the form is submitted, when its values are processed, then you have to use esc_attr(stripslashes($_GET['search'])) so that the value becomes encoded and sql-injections and other format issues are avoided, again this has to happen in the php file where the form is processed, usually after an if ($_GET) statement.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it didn't work. A backslash still breaks the search form, turning the submit button into a text area. =(

Done with default wordpress twenty thirteen theme with no plugins enabled.

Comment: can you make an echo of the $_GT['search']; ? and then an echo of it inside urldecode? and paste here the results?

Comment: Ok, so if i search for a backslash \, `echo $_GET['search'];` and 
`echo urldecode($_GET['search']);` would result to \\ and \\ respectively.

Comment: this means that the value is not encoded when the value is submited. You need to sanitize the value of the text input when the form is submitting, not when the html loads, echo $_GET['search'] had to output %5C for \ so there is something wrong on the code when submitting the form

Comment: but how do i sanitize it? now i'm confused. i tried `sanitize_text_field($_GET['search'])' without success.

Comment: At this point your trobule is not "how" to sanitize it, it's "where" to sanitaize it! you have to sanitize it where the form is beeing procesed

Comment: Like I said, the test form I made is simply just a form. There are no other php codes or other processing that goes with it except the `echo $_GET['search']` at the text value. There is no "where" to sanitize. Unless you are telling me that my hosting provider's php is somehow bugged?

Comment: never said or come close to saying that the hosting provider's php is bugged. if the code is short, if you can share it, would help us debug

Comment: Again, there is no other code! I have shared it all. Clean wordpress install, default theme, no plugins. the only code i have is that form with the `echo $_GET['search']` at the text value.

Comment: is your website live? can you share a link to it, what browser are you using for testing the website? can you take the above steps using chrome and let me know if anything changes?

Comment: I don't think it's a browser issue. I've tried several browsers (chrome, firefox, safari, ie.) but all have resulted the same even at different computers.